# How to extract the first and last 3 columns of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some dataframes and I would like to extract the first 3 and the last 3 column from them separately. And the column names and the column amount of them are different. Could any one give me a tip that how can I do that? Thank you in advance ; )

```
df <- matrix(sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE), 10)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
#I know we can do something like this 
df[,c(1:3,5:6)]
#but I dont know how to select last 3 columns
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ncol()`

```
df[,c(1:3, (ncol(df) - 2):ncol(df))]
#   V1 V2 V3 V8 V9 V10
#1   2  3  8  9 10   1
#2   7  7  7  9  3   6
#3   8  2 10  7  7   4
#4   1  1  3  5  8   5
#5   1  5  8  9  1   1
#6   7 10  5  8  7   1
#7   5  3  3  3 10   4
#8   8  9  1  3  5   6
#9   6  1  6  8  7   7
#10  7  2  9 10 10   9
```

---

Or `length()`

```
idx <- length(df)
df[,c(1:3, (idx - 2):idx)]
```

Comment: Although it's great for readability, I think it's better to use `length` inline rather than give it a variable. Just my novice suggestion. Not sure but wouldn't `n` mask say `n()`?!

Answer (score 5):

We can use `head` and `tail` on the column names

```
df[, c(head(names(df), 3), tail(names(df), 3))]
```